# Not getting the correct output sine wave for the circuit built

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, oscilloscope

I am trying to solve this lab for circuits class, but for some reason, the myDaq oscilloscope software is not showing the correct sine wave to find the question number 3 or 2 in the following image.I have also given the output i am getting.
[image]

Here is the image of the circuit, I made sure the connections are right almost 10 times now. The op-amp number is - TL082

[image]

Comment: Chech the scope settings - you have it set for 5 mS/div - that's only 50 mS for the width of the screen, but your input signal of 1 Hz is 1000 mS per cycle.  The vertical volts/div should be perhaps 2 or 5 Volts/div to get a useful display.

Comment: This helped me solve the answer. I changed the time/div factor to 200ms and in the trigger, i changed from edge to immediate and it gave me a perfect diagram. Thank you, i highly appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 1):

> Not getting the correct output sine wave for the circuit built

it is a rectifier circuit. it would be ***incorrect*** for you to get a sine wave out of it.

Comment: I meant the correct the output, not necessarily sine wave, my bad for bad wording.